# Make divs width and height equal to viewport with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, viewport

I have a one page website that uses jquery scrollLeft to scroll between horizontally aligned divs that will work as pages.

These divs should be 100% width and 100% height (equal to current viewport).

with jquery I did it right:

```
$('.row').css('min-height', $(window).height());

$('.row').css('width', $(window).width());

$(window).resize(function() {

        $('.row').css('min-height', $(window).height());

        $('.row').css('width', $(window).width());

});
```

The problem is that these divs will not be re-sized until the jquery.js is fully loaded and the doc is ready.

So I think the best way is to do it with raw JavaScript. How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried loading jquery right before your `<div class="row">...</div>`
and put the script your wrote right after it?

Comment: I think this is not the best idea, as you should always stick to loading your js files at the end of your html :)

Comment: Yes you're right. I remember I had the same issue on [this website](http://ymammar.com/?q=about). If I correctly understood your problem, the thing is to wait for all the sources to load (not just the html file) before executing the script, using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`